# apache solr - show possibly related search results if no results found

Tags: apache, solr

[i'm a apache solr 4.3 newbie]
Hey,
I want to show possibly related results rather than writing "no results found".
Let say the user searches for "xxxxx", then solr return no results, I want to have a default search for "software engineer" or something like that. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle it on the Client side to fire a Second Query in case of No results found in Solr.
You can use the Spell Check components/Did You mean based on the Index dictionary to provide suitable suggestions to the User instead of firing a default search.

Comment: first of all thank you for the answer, spellcheck components would definitely help, currently i'm using a porterstem and ngram. AFAIK, spellcheck components cant handle well when used with stemming.

Comment: you can have diffferent fields for search and other just to provide suggestions.

Comment: @Jayendra but we can make solr handle a retry a query if no results were found due to an function query right? It can omit the fq and do a raw search.